# How Can I Pass Data From My Visualforce Page To A Visualforce Component Inside of It

Tags: visualforce, visualforce-component

I have several visualforce components inside a Visualforce page.
Instead of doing my SOQL queries inside each component (through an apex controller), I'd like to have a single soql query inside the VF page controller and pass resulting data (ieally as an array) to my VF components.

Current Page Code looks like:
<c:component1 />
<c:component2 />

Is passing values (as an array) into these components through the vf page housing them  possible to do?

Answer (score 2):

Yes it is. You can pass in specific values:

```
<apex:component>
    <apex:attribute name="sobs" type="MyCustomObject__c[]" description=""/>
    ...
</apex:component>
```

or indeed a reference to the page controller

```
<apex:component>
    <apex:attribute name="c" type="PageController" description=""/>
    ...
</apex:component>
```

and then use expressions like `{ !c.property }` to reference values from the controller.

Just a question of whether you want the component to be fully self-contained or not.

Comment: Thanks Keith! This is great to know.